# Is it possible to set a precise frequency with a Btech 50x3 or am I stuck with being off frequency all the time?

Tags: frequency

I can't seem to figure out how to set it to the simplex frequency, 146.520. Always skips to 146.525 or 146.500.

Answer (score 2):

Common solution for this problem is the setting of the frequency step size. That must be different from 25 or 12.5 kHz. Grid step must be set to 20 kHz or 10 kHz or 5 kHz.

According the [technical description](https://baofengtech.com/product/uv-50x3/) that is possible. Scroll to that specification point: "Frequency Step: 2.5KHz/5KHz/6.25KHz/10KHz/12.5KHz/20KHz/25KHz".

Comment: @RClocher: the text is, with the errors that you wanted to improve, a one-to-one copy of the Baofeng document. Just copy-paste. That is why I rolled-back. And you are right: Baofeng misuses Khz an kHz etc.....

Comment: I don't mind that you rolled the edit back Frans, but the implied link should at least be converted to a real link, which was my main goal.  I just had to fix "KHz" and the lack of spacing while I was editing.  No criticism was implied, I know you just copied that from the web page yourself ;)

Comment: Misunderstood that the link was the main target.... Thanks for attention!

Comment: I just edited to make the link a real link.

Comment: Thanks. I have no idea how to add a link in the proper way.....

Comment: If you click on the "?" icon in the editing tool then an editing help pane will open, which is very helpful and doesn't take much space.  It will tell you how to make links and many other tricks in the Markdown syntax that is used on this site.

Comment: Found it; thanks.

Comment: @webmarc Please meet me in [Ham Shack](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11162/ham-shack).

Comment: I may have overcome this by loading some "channels" using the CHIRP software. Not sure but it works fine with my Anytone handset.